# Как сверстать двухколоночный макет таким образом?

Tags: html, css

Приложу примеры в картинках для наглядности.

Есть главная страница такого вида:

> [image: главная]

При переходе в полную новость мы оказываемся на странице с этой новостью, где постер располагается в правой колонке. Сама же правая колонка доступна на главной, но постера конечно же там нет, он слева рядом с описанием новости.

> [image: полная новость на десктопе]

**Вопрос:** Каким образом сверстать такой макет, чтобы получилось так? (забыл показать на картинке. постер должен быть под заголовком полной новости (см HTML код ниже под спойлером, там показан заголовок).

> [image: та самая новость, но уже на мобильном устройстве]

Проблема в том, что я не могу разместить постер под `title` новости в мобильной версии потому, что постер находится в другом блоке.. проблему наглядно можно увидеть в `html` коде (см. ниже)

```html
<div class="content flex">
  <div class="midside">
    <div id="dle-content">
      <div class="block-item">
        <div class="post">
          <div class="post-head">
            <div class="flex flex-center">
              <div class="post-category">
                <a class="category-link" href="/">Фильмы</a>
              </div>
              <h1 class="post-title">
                <div class="title">Люди Икс</div>
                <div class="alt-title">X-Men, 2000 12+</div>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="post-container">
            <div class="post-box">
              <div class="post-text">Они — дети атомного века, сверхлюди, новое звено в цепи эволюции. Каждый из них был рождён в результате уникальной генетической мутации, наделившей их с детства необыкновенными способностями. Под руководством профессора Чарльза Ксавьера,
                телепата с мировым именем, одарённые ученики научились контролировать и управлять своими удивительными способностями в интересах человечества. Но не все мутанты разделяют взгляды профессора: могущественный мутант Магнето, которому подвластны
                все металлы, собрал команду единомышленников. Он не верит, что люди и мутанты когда-либо смогут мирно сосуществовать. Они разработали план, чтобы осуществить захват власти над миром, и тогда, только ученики профессора Ксавьера смогут защитить
                этот мир…</div>
              <div class="post-menu">
                <div class="post-author">
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <span class="cover" style="background-image: url(uploads/fotos/foto_2.png);"></span>
                  </div>
                  <a href="/" class="login-name">Aqua</a>
                </div>
                <a class="post-edit boobls-anim" onclick="return dropdownmenu(this, event, MenuNewsBuild('67', 'full'), '170px')" href="#">
                  <svg class="icn icn-menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                            <path d="M14.667 12c0-0.736-0.3-1.404-0.781-1.885s-1.149-0.781-1.885-0.781-1.404 0.3-1.885 0.781-0.781 1.149-0.781 1.885 0.3 1.404 0.781 1.885 1.149 0.781 1.885 0.781 1.404-0.3 1.885-0.781 0.781-1.149 0.781-1.885zM24 12c0-0.736-0.3-1.404-0.781-1.885s-1.149-0.781-1.885-0.781-1.404 0.3-1.885 0.781-0.781 1.149-0.781 1.885 0.3 1.404 0.781 1.885 1.149 0.781 1.885 0.781 1.404-0.3 1.885-0.781 0.781-1.149 0.781-1.885zM5.333 12c0-0.736-0.3-1.404-0.781-1.885s-1.149-0.781-1.885-0.781-1.404 0.3-1.885 0.781-0.781 1.149-0.781 1.885 0.3 1.404 0.781 1.885 1.149 0.781 1.885 0.781 1.404-0.3 1.885-0.781 0.781-1.149 0.781-1.885z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
    <div class="block-item gffg">
      <div class="block full-play">
        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="flex flex-center flex-center-center">
            <!-- ПОСТЕР -->
            <img class="poster lazy-loaded" data-src="/uploads/.jpg" src="/uploads/posts/2020-10/.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-buttons flex flex-center-center">
          <a class="btn btn-purple" href="/">
            <span class="btn-title">Смотреть онлайн</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-item">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block-head">
          <div class="title">Навигация</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если хотите оставить свои замечания по работе редактора или сайта, задайте вопрос на Мете!

Comment: @HamSter я тут новенький.. я не знаю, что такое мета.. мб с ссылкой писать сразу. редактор убогий, если к изображению добавить спойлер, то по сути он должен свернуться в линию, а он применяет на себя размеры изображения... это ужасно. и все эти теги, будто в dos гамаешь. 2020 год! нормальный визуальный редактор на хабре. вот ещё б комьюнити как тут. вот таким вот полотном в вопросе я только отпугиваю людей, которым просто лень всё это читать. хотя, там мало всего, но визуально - много.

Comment: Мета: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ну у меня в голове только на варианта, современный ( использовать grid, но тогда переделывать достаточно придется ) и костыльный ( сверстай еще один заголовок для mobile  и при нужном разрешении показывай либо стандартный либо мобильный заголовок)

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz да вот.. похоже нужно купить grid, не работал с ним) так-то у меня там код простой, на flex'ах всё реализовано. ох уж этот flex))

Comment: Ох..там на Ютубе курсы есть по гриду. Основу необходимую за час освоите. 
И flex это хорошо. Гриды с флексами обычно сочетают. Грид для структуры страницы а флексы уже для внутренних блоков.

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz Вы же сам сайт смотрели? получается через gri можно будет реализовать такое? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6gpX.png 

на хабре сказали, что не выйдет так, как я хочу, а если и сделать то немного колхозным вариантом. _в данном случае это можно сделать только хаком: разместить 2 постера. Первый между заголовком и текстом, второй в правой колонке и и делать им перекрестный показать/скрыть стилями в медиа-квери_

Comment: Ну я "краем глаза" смотрел. Мне кажется что гридами можно будет такое собрать. Но тут вопрос целесообразности. Если это единственная проблема, то я бы тоже "костылем" сделал. Они вам предложили тоже, о чем я вам выше писал. Только я предлагал 2 заголовка, а  они 2 постера) Но я думаю, что лучше 2 заголовка. Зачем грузить лишние картинки)

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz 2 заголовка h1 вредно же для seo. да и так-то я знаю, про такие способы реализации. но вот grid больше привлекает, может что с ним выйдет.. буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz а что если использовать абсолютное позиционирование? изначально постер разместить в теле новости под тайтлом, а на десктопе придавать постеру ```position: absolute;``` и уже выравнивать его относительно правого сайдбара

Comment: ерунда получится, мое мнение)

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz да так и есть) поэтому, я использовал теги шаблонизатора от cms и реализовал задачу. вроде как работает.